# Getting the following warning message when communicating with a HTTPS Web Service: "Can not find truststore url"

Tags: https, jax-ws, keystore, truststore

I am a beginner with SSL/HTTPS. Hopefully, this isn't a dumb question.

I am writing a web service client that runs on JBOSS 4.3 which communicates with an external web service over https. I have generated the client using the wsimport tool (JAX-WS) that now comes with JDK 1.6. I am sucesfully able to communicate with the web service but I keep getting this warning message in the logs:

WARN  [HTTPClientInvoker] Unable to create SSL Socket Factory for client invoker: Error initializing socket factory SSL context: Can not find truststore url.

From what I understand, as long as the JDK recognizes the certificate (CA) that the service provider is using, there should be no problem with the communication over https. I see that the service provider is using Equifax Secure. I checked my jdk and see that it's already there by default. I am also able to communicate with the service provider but I can't figure out why I am getting the warning message. I read elsewhere that I can potentially solve this problem by setting:

javax.net.ssl.keyStore and javax.net.ssl.trustStore in my jboss run.conf

I'm not sure why I need to do this when my jdk already trusts this certificate. Can someone explain to me why I'm getting this warning message even though my communication is going through. Aslo, can someone explain to me when someone should set the two configuration (javax.net.ssl.keyStore and javax.net.ssl.trustStore) above ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See JBoss JIRA:

Error creating SSL Socket Factory for client invoker: Error initializing socket factory SSL context: Can not find truststore url.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-1133?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issue-tabs